# "It's not a lottery ticket I'd like to buy." - idiom or metaphor?

Tags: idioms, semantics, metaphors

Is "It's not a lottery ticket I'd like to buy" an example of an idiom or a metaphor in this extract? Or could it be something different altogether?

[Context:](https://www.abc.net.au/triplej/programs/hack/coronavirus-covid19-should-the-immune-be-allowed-free-movement/12173710)

> Despite the chance that people may be able to get COVID-19 twice, several countries around the world are considering immunity passports or certificates that could exempt recovered people from coronavirus restrictions.
>
> ...
>
> "Are people going to go off and have corona parties, but not with the beer, and get themselves infected?" he asked.
>
> "I suppose there are always going to be individuals that are going to think that, but there have been cases of quite young and healthy people dying of this.
>
> "It's not a lottery ticket I'd like to buy."

Comment: It's possible for something to be both an idiom *and* a metaphor. The two aren't mutually exclusive. But something is only an idiom if it's in common use. Although the phrase *sounds* nice, I don't believe it's a common expression. Therefore, I'd say it's only a metaphor.

Comment: Nice metaphor, though. Fresh.